# Override event for downloadable product

Tags: magento-1, downloadable, reorder, download-link

I want to override event for method `saveDownloadableOrderItem` :

```
<adminhtml>
   <sales_order_item_save_commit_after>
     <observers>
        <downloadable_observer>
              <class>downloadable/observer</class>
              <method>saveDownloadableOrderItem</method>
          </downloadable_observer>
      </observers>
  </sales_order_item_save_commit_after>
</adminhtml>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
If you want to add some more logic int he method `saveDownloadableOrderItem` but still be able to call the original method you can do this.
Create a new module and in the `config.xml` file of it, under the `global`  tag, add this:

```
<models>
    <downloadable>
        <rewrite>
            <observer>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</observer>
        <rewrite>
    </downloadable>
</models>
```

then create the file `[Namespace]/[Module]/Model/Observer.php` in your module with this content

```
public function saveDownloadableOrderItem($observer)
{
    //your code here.
}
```

**Option 2**
If you want to completely disable the original method and use your own you can do this:
Create a module and in the `config.xml` file add this code:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <sales_order_item_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
               <downloadable_observer>
                   <class>[yourmodule]/observer</class>
                   <method>yourMethodName</method>
               </downloadable_observer>
            </observers>
         </sales_order_item_save_commit_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: why not in <events> ?

Comment: I don't understand. what do you mean? You want to completely change what happens? I mean, that method should not be called at all, instead your method should be called?

Comment: Yes I want to called my method instead of "saveDownloadableOrderItem" .

Comment: I've edited the answer. But there is on catch. If you chose option 2 your class & method will be called only on the admin part. the frontend part will still use the original method. With the first approach, your new method will be called for both admin  & frontend.